# .net using regex to extract a pattern from a string

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string that can contain any number of any type of characters. I'm looking to use regex to extract patterns and put them into a String that I can later manipulate.

Ex: I want regex to extract all 3 digit sequences. So if I have a string that says "Easy as 123" I would get "123" from it.

BTW This is for C#.net and VB.net

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(\d+)`

```
(       start capturing group
   \d   capture digits
+       capture one or more
)       end capturing group
```

That will extract digits. But I recommend you read up on [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) so you can learn the conventions and write your own. Try using [regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to test them too.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. Regex is not my strong point. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @PaulG You can browse the regex tag here on SO to get a feel for more complex regexs to aid your understanding. Good luck. (If the answer helped, make sure to hit the green check mark to accept it)

Comment: Thanks. I would accept the answer but I have to wait 8 minutes